# How to make VSC aware of Alt gr key in keybindings definition?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code. I'm developing C/C++ software for ESP32 processors, using ESP-IDF SDK. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

In terminal I need to do <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to stop monitoring programs (after `make monitor`). In my keyboard (PT keyboard, non US keyboard), to enter `]` I need to press <kbd>Alt gr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> (the key <kbd>9</kbd> also has the `)` and `]`).

Doing `Crtl + Alt gr + 9` in VSC is the same as `Crtl + 9`. It switch to the last editor.

[image: Picture added]

<kbd>Alt gr</kbd> key is `ISO_Level3_Shift` (outout of `xev -event keyboard`):

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
root 0x25b, subw 0x0, time 6860797, (76,-14), root:(2078,566),
state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How to I make VSC aware of <kbd>Alt gr</kbd> key?

Answer (score 0):

I can not make <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> different from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt gr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>. But I found a workaround.

To send the <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to the shell, I've edited the `keybinding.json` with:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+9",
    "command": "-workbench.action.lastEditorInGroup"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+9",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "\u001d"
    }
}
```

Basically, I remove the existing keybind and added a new one, using [workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding).

Unicode character `\u001d` is <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.